# Power Apps runs on Android Device Without Microsoft Power Apps

Tags: dynamics-crm, office365-apps, powerapps

I created an app in Microsoft Power Apps. how do execute an app without Microsoft Power Apps?

Comment: "How to" questions are too broad off-topic questions in SO..

Comment: Do you want to run the power app using web URL or you want something like you could download it from playstore or app store and use it?

Answer (score 1):

Apps made with PowerApps can be only used with either the browser using https://home.dynamics.com or with the PowerApps apps from the respective Apple, Google or Microsoft stores. They cannot be used outside of the PowerApps ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

No, it only run in Microsoft power platform or used with either the browser (like https://home.dynamics.com, here 'home' is your app name when you create)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that you will need the Powerapps client in platform that you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft power apps do not give the freedom of allowing their apps to run outside their ecosystem like a standalone app. Every app developed and deployed using powerapps must still run in Microsoft ecosystem.
You can also use the [play.powerapps.com](https://play.powerapps.com) to preview them on any browser after authenticating with your power apps login.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is that you can't install the application as a stand-alone programme. If you don't have a power apps account, you can't utilise the programme since Microsoft only allows you to create and share programmes in the power apps environment. Outside of the power apps' environment, it cannot be accessed.**

Use Chrome or another browser to access it.
just follow the steps:

1. login to your power apps account.
2. open your app and then go to file menu.
3. then go to share tab.
4. There, you must enter the mail ID of the person you wish to share the application with.
5. When you do this, an email created by Outlook will be sent to the recipient you specify, notifying them that you have shared the application with them. then they can use the URL they received in the mail to access the application. (The user must possess a power apps account.)
6. or you could share the link by going to the details option in your power apps and from there you can copy the web link to access the applicaion. but first you need to follow the steps mentioned in step 4.

If you find this answer helpful please mark it as solved.
or you could tell me whether it is helpful or not using comments.

Happy development :)

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible using the App Wrap feature.

Once you enable this feature in your environment you can wrap an app which generates an android and/or iOS app which you can sign and deploy.

You can find the latest documentation for how to it here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/common/wrap/overview

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use power platform application in your device and access the app you built.

Answer (score -1):

You can run them in the web without installing PowerApps for Android. Go to https://web.powerapps.com/ on your phone's browser to see your list of apps and run them.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I need another help. Can I use web apps without Microsoft  Organisation  account Authentication?  We need to use dynamics 365 portal authentication in Power Apps. Give a video demo or tutorial